# In C/C++ extensions to Python, what reference count should a returned PyObject* have?

Tags: python, c++, c, reference-counting, python-c-extension

Lets say you wrote a C++ (or C) extension to python, called `module`. It returns an array of arrays. What should  the returned array, and its arrays, have as reference counts?

The python code would be something like

```
import my_module
from sys import getrefcount as g      # will use to check reference count

def use_module():
   x = my_module.func()
   print 'x =', x
   print 'g(x) =', g(x)
   print 'g(x[0]) =', g(x[0])
   test = 'some random thing'
   print 'should be', g(test), '?'

use_module()
>>> x = ( (1,2,3,4) , [2,3] , {'one':1} )
>>> g(x) = 3
>>> g(x[0]) = 3
>>> should be 2 ?
```

I would expect `g(x)` to be `2`, not `3`. (after adding one for `g` to reference `x`)

In my C++ extension, I have made sure that the array and all its sub-collections and their elements have reference counts of `1` before being returned to python, so I'm not sure how it shot up to `3` so quickly? Perhaps returned `PyObject*`'s should have `0` as its reference count?

Edit: sorry, I'm an idiot. I was making another reference without knowing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no other references to the returned object exist, the refcount should be 1. If the refcount were 0, the object would get deallocated.

Comment: To be clearer, https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/intro.html#reference-count-details tells exactly when the refcount stuff has to happen, i. e. it tells about reference receiving, borrowing, stealing etc.